# mysql SUM CASE self join

Tags: mysql, sum, case, self, self-join

i need some help with this query

this is the actual result of my query

```
price received   qty recieved    price release  qty release     
  10.30              10                0             0                
   0                  0              10.30           2  
   0                  0              10.30           1
  19.20              20               0              0
   0                  0              19.20           5                      
   0                  0              19.20           3                
   0                  0              19.20           1
```

Using this code in my query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN qtyreceived > 0 THEN qtyreceived END) AS qtyrec,
     SUM(CASE WHEN  qtyrelease > 0 THEN qtyrelease END) AS qtyrel 
     FROM stockledger 
     WHERE stockdesc= '$_POST[desc]' GROUP BY pricerelease,pricereceived ");
```

the results was

price received       qtyreceived    price release  qtyrelease    bal
     10.30            10                                         10
     19.20            20                                         20 
                                      10.30           3          -3
                                      19.20           9          -9

and i want to view the result this way so i can get the remaining number for 2 prices

```
 price received       qtyreceived    price release  qtyrelease    bal
         10.30            10              10.30           3        7
         19.20            20              19.20           9        11
```

thanks.....;

Comment: how will you know that `10` will be added by `-3` and `20` will be added by `-9`?

Comment: could u pls provide some raw sample data?

Answer (score 1):

From seeing your data, I think it will be based on the prices. Right? try this one.

```
SELECT  a.PriceReceived,
        a.qtyreceived,
        b.priceRelease,
        b.qtyRelease,
        (a.bal + b.bal) as bal
FROM    stockledger a 
            INNER JOIN stockledger b
                ON a.priceReceived = b.priceRelease
```

or another alternative is

```
SELECT  a.PriceReceived,
        a.qtyreceived,
        b.priceRelease,
        b.qtyRelease,
        (a.qtyreceived - b.qtyRelease) as bal
FROM    stockledger a 
            INNER JOIN stockledger b
                ON a.priceReceived = b.priceRelease
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a6b5/7)